# How do you interpret "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method"?

Tags: java, android

We decided, perhaps naively, that we should update many of our libraries from two-year-old 1.12.0-betas to nice new versions 1.20.0. For example: we updated google-http-client-1.12.0-beta.jar to google-http-client-android-1.20.0.jar.

When we execute this code:

```
  List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList(SendToGoogleUtils.FUSION_TABLES_SCOPE);
  GoogleAccountCredential credential = SendToGoogleUtils.getGoogleAccountCredential(
      context, account.name, scopes );
  if (credential == null) {
    return false;
  }
  Fusiontables fusiontables = new Fusiontables.Builder(
      AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
```

we get this amazing error report:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport;Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/api/client/json/JsonObjectParser;Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/services/GoogleClientRequestInitializer;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V in class Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/services/json/AbstractGoogleJsonClient; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient' appears in /data/app/dkr.ajijic.apps.tm-1/base.apk)
```

Does anybody know how to interpret it? We sure don't!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It just means that a constructor for AbstractGoogleJsonClient with a particular argument list wasn't available.

Check your `super()` calls for your subclass(es) of `AbstractGoogleJsonClient` and make sure you don't need to update the argument list to match your updated libraries.

If that's not in your source code, then there may be a library version dependency issue with Google API client library.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! We never explicitly extend or reference `AbstractGoogleJsonClient`. The Fusiontables Builder does though, and that made me realize that I needed to be more thorough updating ALL relevant libraries. I found I hadn't updated to: google-api-services-fusiontables-v2-rev4-1.20.0.jar . Updating to that got us past this problem. So many thanks for helping get us thinking straight

Answer (score 2):

Had this on Android when the source code target version was higher than the OS version used on the device.
Therefore had access to methods that didn't exist in the library bundled with the OS, hence `NoSuchMethodError`.

Comment: It just happened to me on Android as well. There were no changes on any SDK version or library, no apparent reason. Cleaning up the app data and launching it again solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is happened because of Proguard is applied via Proguard this class name and methods name changes that why NoSuchMethod exception is occurring.

To resolve this error please add below line into you Proguard rules.

> -keep class com.google.** { *; }

Hopefully this will resolve your issue.