# How to debug "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError"?

Tags: android, parsing, facebook-login, back4app

I'm working toward allowing user to login via Facebook using parse server, the integration was successful but go this error (below) when user is trying to login in.

```
02-11 16:33:14.498 20226-20385/com.xpressoftng.betatutor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-8
                                                                           Process: com.xpressoftng.betatutor, PID: 20226
                                                                           java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/Collection;Lcom/facebook/AccessTokenSource;Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/util/Date;)V in class Lcom/facebook/AccessToken; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.facebook.AccessToken' appears in /data/app/com.xpressoftng.betatutor-yiEOpIyeFzKdlNn9Dmp8ZA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                                                                               at com.parse.facebook.FacebookController.setAuthData(FacebookController.java:222)
                                                                               at com.parse.facebook.ParseFacebookUtils$1.onRestore(ParseFacebookUtils.java:119)
                                                                               at com.parse.ParseAuthenticationManager$2.call(ParseAuthenticationManager.java:70)
                                                                               at com.parse.ParseAuthenticationManager$2.call(ParseAuthenticationManager.java:67)
                                                                               at bolts.Task$4.run(Task.java:357)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Perhaps related? Different library but I think the answer is applicable and relevant. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041260/how-do-you-interpret-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-direct-method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you interpret "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041260/how-do-you-interpret-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-direct-method)

Comment: Thanks @aug, Have tried those suggestions, none of them fix the issues

Comment: any code you can share? might help people -- also would be good to point out what you tried in the suggestion as the suggestion is pretty broad in general