# HMS: crash after integrate com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-auth:1.6.4.300

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-account, agconnect-functions

I'm going to use Facebook and google login service, so we integrated com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-auth:1.6.4.300.

However, after integration, the game crashes. as shown below

[image]

Comment: hi@kgsharathkumar, to locate this issue, could you mind provide with more detail about what else AGC or HMS services are integrated and the specific version number?

Comment: This SOF answer might help to point to the right place in your implementation.

Comment: The link is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041260/how-do-you-interpret-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-direct-method